# What is the difference between core2-64-poky-linux and x86_64-linux directory in Yocto which located in build/tmp/work?

Tags: linux, x86-64, yocto, instruction-set

What is the difference between `core2-64-poky-linux` and `x86_64-linux` directories in Yocto Project, which are located in `build/tmp/work/~`?

Some of modules(recipe) are built and their output belong to path `build/tmp/work/core2-64-poky-linux`, some others are in path `build/tmp/work/x86_64-linux`.

I'd like to know what `x86_64` and `core2-64` mean.
I think I knew what `x86_64` is, now I doubt it.

Comment: Presumably https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_Core_2, i.e. `gcc -march=core2`.  So it includes SSSE3, constant_tsc, cmpxchg16b, and a few other CPU features that aren't baseline for x86-64 in general.

Answer (score 0):

The `x86_64-linux` directory is for the native recipes which are compiled in the architecture of the host/building machine.

The `core2-64-poky-linux` directory is for the target recipes, provided the recipes you build are for a core2-64 machine (e.g. qemux86-64).